# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am creating an eCommerce website. I am trying to fetch products categories from the backend, But it shows me an error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined`. But the data is there in the console.

can someone please help me Thanks

Here is my code

Category.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllCategory } from '../../actions';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';

const Category = () => {

    const category = useSelector(state => state.category)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getAllCategory());
    }, []);


    const renderCategories = (categories) => {
        let myCategories =[];
        for(let category of categories) {
            myCategories.push(
                <li key={category.name}>
                    {category.name}
                </li>
            )
        }

        return categories;

    }

    return (
        <Layout sidebar>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12}>
                        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                            <h3>Category</h3>
                            <button>Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12}> 
                        { renderCategories(category.categories) }
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Category
```

Category.js (actions)

```
import axios from "../helper/axios";
import { categoryConstants } from "./constants";

export const getAllCategory = () => {
    return async dispatch => {

        dispatch({ type: categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_REQUEST });
        const res =  await axios.get(`/category/getcategory`);
        console.log(res);

        if(res.status === 200) {

            const { categoryList } = res.data;

            dispatch({
                type: categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
                paylaod : { categories: categoryList }
            });
        }else{
            dispatch({
                type: categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_FAILURE,
                paylaod: { error: res.data.error }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Category.jS(reducers)

```
import { categoryConstants } from "../actions/constants";

const initState = {
    categories: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
};

export default (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
            state = {
                ...state,
                categories: action.payload.categories
            }
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Constants.js

```
export const categoryConstants = {
    GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_REQUEST: 'GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_REQUEST',
    GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:'GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS',
    GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_FAILURE: 'GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_FAILURE'
}
```

[image: This is what I am getting as an error] This is what I am getting as an error.

The data in the console which I am getting from the backend[image]

Comment: There is a typo in your dispatch function - `payLAOD : { categories: categoryList }`

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice